# Read raw SMART data with smartmontools from CF card

Tags: flash-memory, smartctl, smart

I have a [Transcend CompactFlash](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-174) card; its datasheet specifies the SMART data structure i.e. "Power cycle count" is bytes 115-116 in this structure.

I am running on a custom embedded system with Gentoo and linux kernel version 4.12. When I run [smartctl](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in), I get a less than helpful output. But, to my understanding, this is to be expected.

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     ------   100   100   000    -    0
  2 Throughput_Performance  ------   100   100   000    -    0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   ------   100   100   000    -    0
  7 Unknown_Attribute       ------   100   100   000    -    0
  8 Unknown_Attribute       ------   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       ------   100   100   000    -    208
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  ------   100   100   000    -    0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count ------   100   100   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  ------   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ------   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    ------   100   100   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ------   100   100   000    -    0
```

If I connect this card to an IDE adapter to a Windows machine and use Crystal Disk Info, it displays the same info as above, but there is an option to copy the raw data to the clipboard. This raw data contains the 512 byte structure as defined in the datasheet, which I can then parse out myself.

Is there some way for me to access the raw SMART data via `smartctl`? I have read through all the option in the man page and nothing seems to be what I am looking for. If there is no such flag, what are my options? Do I need to write something to directly issue ATA commands and read the SMART data myself?

Answer (score 0):

```
smartctl /dev/sdX | grep -w  12 | awk "{print $8}"
```

/dev/sd**X** repreesents which device you want SMART data from.

We use **12** to have [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) select the Power_Cycle_Control line in the output of [smartctl](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in).

then **$8** to have [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) filter out all but the 8th field.